# PHP output message

Tags: php, wordpress

I need some help regarding PHP output. Actually i am trying to show a message but in return it showing multiple messages on page.

**OUTPUT:**
***Here are some questionsHere are some questionsHere are some questionsHere are some questions***

Here is my code: See Line **#2**

```
function sc_wptabtitle( $atts, $content = null ) {
echo '<span class="acbar">Here are some questions</span>';
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'header'    =>  'h3',
        'hclass'    =>  'wp-tab-title',
        'label'     =>  'text',
        'image_size'=>  '24,24',
        '_id'       =>  false,
        'load'      =>  '',
        'post'      =>  '',
        'page'      =>  '',
        'cat'       =>  '',
        'category_name' => '',
        'tag'       =>  '',
        'tag_name'      =>  '',
        'number'    =>  '4',
        'exclude'   =>  '',
        'tag'       =>  '',
        'feed'      =>  '',
        'hide'      =>  "false",
        'elength'   =>  $this->options['excerpt_length'],
        'before_post'   =>  '',
        'after_post'    =>  '',
        'template'      =>  '1',
        'icon'      =>  false
    ), $atts));

    global $wpui_id_remove_chars;

    if ( str_ireplace( $wpui_id_remove_chars, '', $_id ) != $_id )
        $_id = false;

    $tmpl = ( isset( $this->options[ 'post_template_' . $template ] ) ) ?
                $this->options[ 'post_template_' . $template ] :
                $this->options[ 'post_template_1' ];

     if ( isset( $this->options[ 'title_template' ] ) && $this->options[ 'title_template' ] != '' ) {
         $title_template = $this->options[ 'title_template' ];
        if ( $_id ) {
            $title_template = str_ireplace( '>{$title}', 'id="' . $_id . '">{$title}', $title_template );
        }
     } else {
         $title_template = '<' . $header;
         $title_template .= ' class="' . $hclass . '"';
         if ( $_id ) {
             $title_template .= ' id="' . $_id . '"';
         }
         $title_template .= '>{$title}</' . $header . '>'; 
     }
```

Any guess why it is showing multiple messages/text lines on output page?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because of you are calling the function `sc_wptabtitle` multiple times in your code.

So it is calling the below code

```
echo '<span class="acbar">Here are some questions</span>';
```

multiple times and it is giving such output.

Check your code that where is it calling. May be it will be in loop or called multiple times.

Comment: Yes i know, But is there any way to make it to show only one message on output page?